# .NET - Doesn't exist an event named RowEditEnded or something for datagrid in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I am doing this:

private void dataGrid1_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {

```
        Person newPerson = ((Person)dataGrid1.SelectedItem);
        foreach (Person person in lista)
        {
            if(person.Id == newPerson.Id)
            {
                person.Name = newPerson.Name;
                person.Salary = newPerson.Salary;
            }
        }


    }
```

but when I press "enter" after editing a row, the name isnt changed at newPerson object.
I think it's because this event is "Ending", and not "ended".

I already binded the thing in mode twoWay. Like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Right - the Ending (as with all XXXing events) is fired "before" the row edit is committed ("Occurs before a row edit is committed or canceled." - MSDN). What is the code that you want to do in the post-event - Can it be executed as a PropertyChanged handler for the bound property ?

Answer (score 1):

The event name is RowEditEnding.  Just make sure the event handler name in your XAML matches the name of the handler in your code behind.  That being said, you would get an exception if you didn't have the names matching up.

Comment: what I mean, is that I want a event that occurs when the change ends.

Comment: RowEditEnding is the event that is fired when the user leaves the row bing edited.  Not sure why your data is not being updated.  Can you post more code?  Maybe alter your binding to include "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"?